# Apache 2.4 + htaccess Require all denied = [authz_core:error] AH01630: client denied by server configuration

Tags: apache, .htaccess, require

Ubuntu 18.04 + Php 7.4 + Apache 2.4

Everything working fine, websites are ok.

But i use .htaccess to protect some files or directories.

On previous apache, i used

```
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
```

But i got the error

```
        [access_compat:error]  AH01797: client denied by server configuration:
```

So i update the htaccess with apache 2.4 code

```
        <Files ".ht*">
        Require all denied
        </Files>
```

But now i got the error

```
        [authz_core:error]  AH01630: client denied by server configuration:
```

What's wrong ?
How to fix that ?

Thanks

Comment: You used code to deny access for _all_ requests, and now you are wondering, that you are getting an error, saying access is denied? I don’t get what your question is here, resp. what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: i wonder why i have in log " [authz_core:error] "

I could use htaccess require to protect file, directory
Allow only specifics ip to access another one.
etc.

If the rule does the job ( allow, deny, restricted ) i m just suprised to have a such line in error_log

so it's normal to have  [authz_core:error] ?

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/ClientDeniedByServerConfiguration: _“This error means that the access to the directory on the file system was denied by an Apache configuration.”_

Comment: Oh oki, it's totaly normal so.
Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As CBroe said,
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/ClientDeniedByServerConfiguration
in fact, it's a normal msg.
No error.

Comment: 1) [authz_core:error] is saying it's an error. 2) The article you cite is a good list of possible causes of this error. Please consider reading it again.